# Complex Left Outer Self-Join in Rails 5

Tags: join, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a `list_events` table where I want to get the latest event per user per list between a certain time. Here's an example of the table.

```
id   user_id  list_id  event   created_at
1    5        1        sub     13:45
2    1        1        sub     14:01
3    1        2        sub     14:02
4    3        1        sub     14:03
5    4        1        sub     14:04
6    1        1        unsub   14:05
```

The last events per user for list 1 between 14:00 and 15:00 would be...

```
id   user_id  list_id  event   created_at
4    3        1        sub     14:03
5    4        1        sub     14:04
6    1        1        unsub   14:05
```

In my Rails 5 model I've written the query like so:

```
list.events
    .joins("
      left outer join list_events b
        on  list_events.user_id = b.user_id
        and list_events.list_id = b.list_id
        and list_events.created_at < b.created_at
    ")
    .where("b.user_id is null")
    .where(created_at: start..end)
```

This works fine, but I'm wondering if there's a way to write this without hand-coding the join. I do notice Rails has a `left_outer_join` method, but there's no way to specify custom `on`. Perhaps with a `belongs_to`?

Also if there's a way to alias `list_events` as `a` while still being able to take advantage of the `list.events` relationship abstraction.